# How to replace less-than sign and greater than sign in string which contains onclick event use RegExp

Tags: asp.net

Example :

```
  string a="<div onclick="javascript:alert('111');"></div>"
```

I would like to get result:

```
   &lt;div onclick="javascript:alert('111');" &gt;&lt;/div&gt;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string a = "<p style='font-style: italic' onclick='alert('hacked!!');'>Hello World</p>";
                string b =
        Regex.Replace(
            a,
            @"(<[\s\S]*?) on.*?\=(['""])[\s\S]*?\2([\s\S]*?>)",
            delegate(Match match)
            {
                string br = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string bbb = match.Groups[2].Value;
                return String.Concat(match.Groups[1].Value,match.Groups[3].Value);
            }, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                Response.Write(b);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string a = Server.HtmlEncode("<div onclick=\"javascript:alert('111');\"></div>");
string a2 = Server.HtmlEncode(a);
Response.Write( a2);
```